# Mode of Joint Posterior - Maximization Problems

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, posterior, expectation-maximization, extreme-value

I have a problem whereby I get two different answers if I try to maximize a function.

let
$ \begin{bmatrix} Y_{o}\\ Y_{a}  \end{bmatrix}|\phi\sim N (0,\phi^{-1}A^{-1}) $

$\pi(\phi)=\frac{1}{\phi}$,

where $Y_{o} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{o}}$, $Y_{a} \in \mathbb{R}^{n_{a}}$

I am trying to find the mode of the joint posterior

$f(Y_{a},\phi|Y_{o})$

**Method 1**

$f(Y_{a},\phi|Y_{o})=f(Y_{a}|\phi,Y_{o})f(\phi|Y_{o})$.

$f(Y_{a}|\phi,Y_{o})$ is normal and its mode is independent of $\phi$, so $Y_{a}^{*}=-A_{aa}^{-1}A_{ao}Y_{o}$. $\phi^{*}$ is then the mode of $f(\phi|Y_{o})$ , $\phi^{*}=\frac{n_{o}-2}{Y_{o}^{T}A_{oo.a}Y_{o}}$

**Method 2**

Maximizing the log of the joint.

$\log f(Y_{a},\phi|Y_{o})=$
$-\frac{\phi}{2} Y_{o}^{T}A_{oo.a}Y_{o} -\frac{\phi}{2}(Y_{a}+A_{aa}^{-1}A_{ao}Y_{o})^{T}A_{aa}(Y_{a}+A_{aa}^{-1}A_{ao}Y_{o})
+\frac{n_{o}+n_{a}-1}{2}\log \phi$

yields 
$Y_{a}^{*}=-A_{aa}^{-1}A_{ao}Y_{o}$

and
$\phi^{*}=\frac{n_{o}+n_{a}-2}{Y_{o}^{T}A_{oo.a}Y_{o}}$

**Modal $\phi^{*}$ differ by $n_{a}$**

I don't know why they differ by $n_{a}$, where is my error?